# Rename directory while increasing the number if exists

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to rename a directory, and what I am trying to do is simply increase the number if it already exists.

**Example**
`Folder` will be renamed to `Folder1`
Now lets stay there is a `Folder` and a `Folder1`
Running the application again would now make `Folder` renamed to `Folder2` and so on.

**Current Code**

```
If Directory.Exists(path2) Then
            Try
                My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameDirectory(path2, "Application Data.old")
            Catch
                Exit Sub
            End Try
 End If
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

This is pseudo-code. You need to turn it into real code. Here how you do it

```
 Imports System.IO
 Imports System.Linq

 Dim newFolderName As String
 Dim dirs() As String Directory.GetDirectories("<base dit path>") 'BTW - Directory is real object name
 If dirs.Length > 0 Then 
     Dim maxDir As Integer = dirs.Select(
         Function(d)
             Dim dirNO As Integer 
             If d.StartsWith("Folder") AndAlso d.Length > 6 AndAlso
                 Integer.TryParse(d.Substring(6), dirNO)) Then
                 Return dirNO
             Else
                 Return 0
             End If
         End Function).Max()
     newFolderName = "Folder" & (maxDir + 1)
     If Directory.Exists("<base dit path>\Folder") Then 
         Directory.Rename("<base dit path>\Folder", newFolderName)
     End if
 Else
     Directory.Create("Folder")
 End If
```

Comment: That looks like exactly what I need. I left for the day, but I will try that in the  morning and post results. Thank you so much for the time!

Comment: @dwb You need to tweak it little bit into real code but it should cover. Let me know if issues occur